# Direct Ethernet link between Raspberry CM4 and Jetson Orin Nano

Tags: pcb, ethernet, routing, network, rj45

I need to have high speed communication between Raspberry CM4 and Jetson Orin Nano modules on the same PCB.

My question is: can I route them through Ethernet directly without the need for an isolator like in common RJ45 ports?

And do I have to cross any pairs, i.e. pair 0 on 2 and pair 1 on 3? Or can I connect 0 on 0 etc. directly?

Comment: You need to figure out if both modules support connections without transformers or not. The problem is, it may be impossible to find out documentation which explicitly says if transformerless operation is either supported or not supported, so it may remain unknown. If the mode of the MDI driver operation (current or voltage) is known, it might be guessed if it is possible or not. Now, you only need to find the datasheets that tell these. Unfortunately the Nvidia datasheet is not downloadable without registration so they can have it their way.

Comment: Ok, that closes it, the Jetson datasheet specifically refers to "GbE Transformer" in pin description. 
Altough, I still don't understand if I have to add one or two transformers, and if pair crossing is required.

Comment: It depends. Most likely it says that because that's what you would normally connect. It might support capacitive coupling but you need to ask the manufacturer for support. Pair crossing you can solve for yourself, the pairs are connected identically regardless of amount of transformers on the path. I have no answer if one transformer is OK, as usually you need center taps on the PHY side, and even if there are center taps for cable side, it is unknown if they are suitable for use as center taps for the other PHY, so two sets of transistors is the safest option.